# myModel.save() => rejected promise with status 201

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

When I call myModel.save(), in one of my controllers, to insert a new record into the store I get back a promise with isRejected: true.

The **reason** object has the following attributes:

readyState: 4,
status: 201,
statusText: "created"

The object is created properly in my backend REST service. In fact, if I put the transitionToRoute in the catch(), instead of the then(), everything would appear to be just fine.

What's going on here?

Comment: What version of ember-data?

Comment: ember-data version 1.0.0-beta.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return the object back with your request.  This is particularly important because the server should provide an id for that newly created record.  Without an id there is no definitive way of updating and being sure you're updating the correct record.  The format should follow the same format if you were to `find` the model.

IE:

```
{
  type: {
    id:12312,
    property:'value',
    otherProperty:'value'
  }
}
```